# http post request in java script has 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error but the same request works in fiddler

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest, request

I want to send post request to another domain and get json data back.

I tried post request using fiddler and here is the result: I've got access_token(it's highlighted)

[image]

The problem appears when I'm trying to send it from javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://worldcuppool.local:2490/token",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: 'grant_type=password&username=Oleksandr&password=odin21',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var value = responseData.access_token;
        console.log(responseData);
    },
    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('POST failed.');
    }
});
```

This results in

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://worldcuppool.local:2490/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:58402' is therefore not allowed access.
```

**BUT** in the fiddler I can also see the request from javascript and there response is 'valid' and I can read access_token.

How to get json data back to my javascript?